# Wrong with hallo.js

Tags: markdown, hallo-js

Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...)[plugin] is not a function

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('.editable').hallo({
        plugins: {
            'halloformat': {},
            'halloblock': {},
            'hallojustify': {},
            'hallolists': {},
            'hallolink': {},
            'halloreundo': {},
            'halloimages': {}
        },
        editable: true,
        toolbar: 'halloToolbarFixed',
        placeholder: ''
    });

});
```

I use it in my node project,and include it in my static html.

```
<script src="/public/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/log4javascript.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/core.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/hallo.js"></script>
```

So ,what's wrong? 
I want to use a markdown editor like this, do you have some others?
Thank you.

Comment: You do not include jQuery itself.

Comment: <script src="/public/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>  I had include it，but I forgot to send in my question.